# My htaccess redirect don't work when i specify a word to match

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am locked since hours on a rewrite rule i spend a lot of time looking old questions in stackoverflow and other blogs but i still don't understand ...

I just want to redirect users entering a specific URL containing word investment

So i did this for example :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)investment(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And then nothing happens but when i try this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The rewrite rule work ... But that is not what i want ^^

my original htaccess is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Les directives (lignes) entre 'BEGIN WordPress' et 'END WordPress' sont
# généré dynamiquement, et ne doivent uniquement être modifiées via les filtres WordPress.
# Toute modification des directives entre ces marqueurs sera outrepassée.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I am really lost on how does this rewrite works, if someone know why my redirect is not working, it would be cool ^^

Thanks in advance all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have some other rule(s) modifying `REQUEST_URI`. You can try this rule with `THE_REQUEST` variable

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)investment [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

---

**After latest edit of question:**

You can insert this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)investment https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

just below `RewriteBase` line and retest.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i tried it and get internal server error, this should be an easy redirect i don't understand why i am failing ..

Comment: Yes it don't throw error but it is not redirecting. I still have https://example.com/investment/whatever not redirecting users :s What does the %1 mean ?

Comment: oh ok so this is WP. Can you inset this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)investment https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]` just below `RewriteBase` line and retest.

Comment: Awesome writing it just below worked like a charm ^^ Thank you a lot really for taking time :) I will try to understand this cause i need to add some conditions to this rewrite ^^